# How to visualize a .txt or .csv file on a QTableView after triggering currentRowChanged(int currentRow) on QListWidget?

Tags: c++, csv, qt5, qtableview, qlistwidget

**Problem:** How to visualize a `.txt` or `.csv` file on a `QTableView` after triggering `currentRowChanged(int currentRow)` on `QListWidget`?

I have a very simple interface that I designed as a *minimal verifiable example* that look like below with a `QPushButton` a `QLineEdit` a `QListWidget` and a `QTableView`.

If I upload a `.csv` file using the `QPushButton` there are no problem and the content of the file is correctly shown on a `QTableView`:

[image: via push button]

**However, and here is the problem:**

When I drag and drop (functionality correctly implemented) multiple files and I click on one of them I have problem visualizing the file because the content does not change. It seems that the slot `currentRowChanged(int currentRow)` in the `QListWidget` is never triggered despite the files exists.

[image]

**Below is the desired result:**

[image: desired]

Here is the example I implemented. If you copy/paste on your computer it will work no problem:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum fileFormat {
        CSV,
        TXT,
        OTHER
    };

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void showFilesDetails(QListWidgetItem *item);
    void readFile(QString path, fileFormat format);
    void setValueAt(int ix, int jx, const QString &value);
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);

private slots:
    void on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow);
    void on_loadBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    fileFormat *format;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QDragLeaveEvent>
#include <QDragMoveEvent>
#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace constants
{
const QStringList HEADERS = {
    "tax_id", "Org_name", "GeneID", "CurrentID", "Status"};
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(constants::HEADERS);
    model->setColumnCount(constants::HEADERS.length());
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeMode::ResizeToContents);

    QHeaderView *horizontal = new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, ui->tableView);
    horizontal->setSectionsClickable(true);
    horizontal->setHighlightSections(true);
    ui->tableView->setHorizontalHeader(horizontal);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){ delete ui; }

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) { event->accept(); }
void MainWindow::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event) { event->accept(); }
void MainWindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)   { event->accept(); }

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QString name;
    QList<QUrl> urls;
    QList<QUrl>::Iterator i;
    urls = event->mimeData()->urls();
    for(i = urls.begin(); i != urls.end(); ++i) {
        name = i->path();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(name);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = nullptr;
    if(ui->listWidget->count() > 0)
        ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(currentRow);
    showFilesDetails(item);
}

void MainWindow::readFile(QString path, fileFormat format)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = nullptr;
    QFile file(path);

    if(!file.exists()){
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<path;
    }else{
        qDebug() << path<< "File exist...";
    }
    if (file.fileName().endsWith(".txt", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<file.fileName();
    } else if(file.fileName().endsWith(".csv", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<file.fileName();
    }
    QString line;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        while (!stream.atEnd()){
            line = stream.readLine();
            ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
            qDebug() << "line: "<<line;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::showFilesDetails(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QString path;
    fileFormat frmt;
    readFile(path, frmt);
    ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
}

void MainWindow::on_loadBtn_clicked()
{
    auto filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open", QDir::rootPath(), "CSV file (*.csv)");
    if(filename.isEmpty()) {
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("File empty");
        return;
    }
    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("File did not open");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream xin(&file);
    int ix = 0;
    while (!xin.atEnd()) {
        model->setRowCount(ix);
        auto line = xin.readLine();
        auto values = line.split(",");
        const int colCount = values.size();
        model->setColumnCount(colCount);
        for(int jx = 0; jx < colCount; ++jx) {
            setValueAt(ix, jx, values.at(jx));
        }
        ++ix;
        ui->lineEdit->setText(filename);
        ui->statusbar->showMessage(filename);
    }
    ui->listWidget->addItem(filename);
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::setValueAt(int ix, int jx, const QString &value)
{
    if (!model->item(ix, jx)) {
        model->setItem(ix, jx, new QStandardItem(value));
    } else {
        model->item(ix, jx)->setText(value);
    }
}
```

In order to solve the problem I read very useful sources and in particular I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353026/qtableview-output-save-as-csv-or-txt), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354200/uploading-csv-or-txt-file-to-populate-qtableview) and also I found [this post useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214762/qlistwidget-currentrowchanged-rollback). However, I am trying to figure out where the problem might be.
The drag/drop functionality is properly implemented but how do I upload the files in the `QTableView` and properly trigger the `QListWidget` event?
Thank to anyone who would have time to read and point to a potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik,funtion `on_listWidget_currentRowChanged` triggered properly.
function `showFilesDetails` passes an empty string to `readFile`,this may be the problem.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QDragLeaveEvent>
#include <QDragMoveEvent>
#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace constants
{
const QStringList HEADERS = {
    "tax_id", "Org_name", "GeneID", "CurrentID", "Status"};
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(constants::HEADERS);
    model->setColumnCount(constants::HEADERS.length());
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeMode::ResizeToContents);

    QHeaderView *horizontal = new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, ui->tableView);
    horizontal->setSectionsClickable(true);
    horizontal->setHighlightSections(true);
    ui->tableView->setHorizontalHeader(horizontal);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){ delete ui; }

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) { event->accept(); }
void MainWindow::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event) { event->accept(); }
void MainWindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)   { event->accept(); }

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QString name;
    QList<QUrl> urls;
    QList<QUrl>::Iterator i;
    urls = event->mimeData()->urls();
    for(i = urls.begin(); i != urls.end(); ++i) {
        name = i->toLocalFile();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(name);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = nullptr;
    if(ui->listWidget->count() > 0)
        ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(currentRow);
    showFilesDetails(item);
}

void MainWindow::readFile(QString path, fileFormat format)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = nullptr;
    QFile file(path);

    if(!file.exists()){
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<path;
    }else{
        qDebug() << path<< "File exist...";
    }
    if (file.fileName().endsWith(".txt", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<file.fileName();
    } else if(file.fileName().endsWith(".csv", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug() << "File does not exist "<<file.fileName();
    }file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream xin(&file);
    int ix = 0;
    while (!xin.atEnd()) {
        model->setRowCount(ix);
        auto line = xin.readLine();
        auto values = line.split(",");
        const int colCount = values.size();
        model->setColumnCount(colCount);
        for(int jx = 0; jx < colCount; ++jx) {
            setValueAt(ix, jx, values.at(jx));
        }
        ++ix;
        ui->lineEdit->setText(path);
        ui->statusbar->showMessage(path);
    }
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::showFilesDetails(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    item=ui->listWidget->currentItem();
    QString path=
            item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();;
    fileFormat frmt;
    readFile(path, frmt);
    ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
}

void MainWindow::on_loadBtn_clicked()
{
    auto filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open", QDir::rootPath(), "CSV file (*.csv)");
    if(filename.isEmpty()) {
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("File empty");
        return;
    }
    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        ui->statusbar->showMessage("File did not open");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream xin(&file);
    int ix = 0;
    while (!xin.atEnd()) {
        model->setRowCount(ix);
        auto line = xin.readLine();
        auto values = line.split(",");
        const int colCount = values.size();
        model->setColumnCount(colCount);
        for(int jx = 0; jx < colCount; ++jx) {
            setValueAt(ix, jx, values.at(jx));
        }
        ++ix;
        ui->lineEdit->setText(filename);
        ui->statusbar->showMessage(filename);
    }
    ui->listWidget->addItem(filename);
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::setValueAt(int ix, int jx, const QString &value)
{
    if (!model->item(ix, jx)) {
        model->setItem(ix, jx, new QStandardItem(value));
    } else {
        model->item(ix, jx)->setText(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! I was indeed passing an empty string without realizing it. It took me a very long time to properly write the question and prepare the example, so I really appreciate your time in looking at it!